# Inserting a php file into a Wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have had a customs script made to output a certain phone number depending on where a user has come from. I have been able to set this up within the header of a website using the simple snippet of:

```
<?php include 'TelephoneNumber.php';?>
```

I now need to create a shortcode so that I can call this within the Wordpress test editor. I have created a very simple shortcode but I cannot work out how to include the filename above.

custom_shortcodes.php (placed in the wp-content folder)

```
<?php
function telephone_number(){
return 'PHONE NUMBER HERE';
} // End telephone_number()
?>
```

function.php (themes)

```
include(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/custom_shortcodes.php');
add_shortcode( 'telephone_number_sc', 'telephone_number' );
```

At the minute the shortcode does output the text PHONE NUMBER HERE. However, this is useless as it's not calling the script I need.

How can I use the include file function?

Answer (score 0):

You can either have the function in the same file as the shortcode or you can have them in separate files, but they will need to be structured correctly. Include works the same way as require, I just prefer require.

### In the same file

#### In functions.php

you need to require/include the shortcode file:

```
require('custom_shortcodes.php');
```

#### In custom_shortcodes.php

```
// phone number function
function telephone_number(){
        return 'PHONE NUMBER HERE';
} // End telephone_number()
```

To make shortcode, you need to follow a specific way:

```
//shortcode
function output_shorcode($atts, $content = null){
     $number = telephone_number();
     return $number;
}
add_shortcode( 'number', 'output_shortcode' );
```

and put [number] where ever you need to have the number

### In separate files

#### In functions.php

you need to require/include the shortcode file and the number file:

```
require('phone_number.php');
require('custom_shortcodes.php');
```

#### In custom_shortcodes.php

```
function output_shorcode($atts, $content = null){
         $number = telephone_number();
         return $number;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'number', 'output_shortcode' );
```

#### In phone_number.php

```
// phone number function
    function telephone_number(){
            return 'PHONE NUMBER HERE';
    } // End telephone_number()
```

Comment: Hi Kylar, thanks for the reply! The 'PHONE NUMBER HERE' I want to remove this and try to include the TelephoneNumber.php file as this contains a lot of other code to display a certain number depending on where they have come from etc. Is this still the correct way to do it? I have got my script to work by simply placing <?php include 'TelephoneNumber.php';?> within a php file but I cannot add PHP into the wordpress HTML text editor so I thought using a shortcode would be the best route. Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex, you're welcome. I would have a master phone number function inside the telephoneNumber.php file which combines all the other functions and outputs it and have the shortcode return that function. Shortcode is the best way to consistently output the write number where you want it.